# What does try_files do in this nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

I copied this config when setting up a basic  Nginx / PHP-FPM webserver

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

It works as it should, but I dont understand how the `try_files` in `location ~ \.php$ { .... }` block works when serving a request for a php file, e.g. `domain.com/test.php`.
I thought this line

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

tells nginx to just go ahead and try serving the static file - i.e. append `$uri` to `root` directory, if the file exists - nginx would simply send the static file and the request would be over wouldn't it?
And therefore the `fastcgi_pass` wouldn't occur? but `php-fpm` does get it and execute the script.
Why doesn't the `try_files` prevent the `fastcgi_pass`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`try_files` does not tell `nginx` to serve the static file. Reaching the closing brace in the absence of any other operation causes it to serve the static file. `try_files` tests for the existence of the file in the local file system and may rewrite the URL.

So `try_files $uri =404;` is one of a number of common tricks to overcome a particular script injection exploit by ensuring the the PHP file is a *real*  file before sending the URL to the upstream interpreter.

Comment: Oh ok, so  `try_files`  check for the existence of `$root$uri` , if it does exist, it only remembers it - then continues  processing the rest of the `location` block . If nothing else specifies what to do with the request/file - then nginx serves the static file as a last resort?

Comment: @user4668401 Yes. But a location block is not *required* to contain a `try_files` directive in order for `nginx` to serve static files from that location.

Comment: I see,and if you do have a `try_files` in a location block and it doesn't match a to a file, then it stops any more processing of the current location block and generates an new internal redirect using the final value of the `try_files`?

Comment: Yes. There are a number of directives that can do that.

Comment: DUDE... I spent HOURS trying to figure out why doesn't `try_files` work, when I had made sure the files exist, tried with and without `root`, tried with actually hardcoded paths, etc... always 404!!! Your first paragraph was CRUCIAL to make me finally understand why `try_files` doesn't work. I needed to do a manual `rewrite` first, to remove the prefix of the URL, for `try_files` to work. It all made sense after learning that `try_files` does NOT serve the files! Thank you very much! +1

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it should? [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) doesn't say anything like that.

> Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the
>   first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. [...] If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

As long as the file is found, the request is processed normally, i.e. passed to fastcgi. Otherwise a 404 will be sent.

Comment: oh so, try files is kind of like a guard that says *If I can't find the underlying file - then no further processing of this location block will take place* ? the fallback will be used and an internal redirect will send processing back to the start again?